# Possibility to upload Wagtail documents to a subfolder of /documents/

Tags: django, media, wagtail

I am serving my Django-Wagtail media files trough Amazon S3 and now I reached a point where I need to define a customized Document Class which creates "*restricted*" documents (only accesible if you are logged). This documents will have a special access that will say to my S3 bucket "*hey! just deliver this files If they are requested from this "foo_url" but not from anywhere else"*, since they will be shown to logged users only. I thought of this to **prevent restricted urls to spread out**.

That's why I am trying to define this Wagtail Document class to be stored in a **subfolder** of **/documents/** and just tell Amazon what to do with that subfolder.

*dummy_code_that_doesnt_work*:

```
class RestrictedDocument(Document):
    def get_upload_to(self, filename):
        folder_name = 'restricted'
        filename = self.file.field.storage.get_valid_name(filename)
        return os.path.join(folder_name, filename)

"""
Snippet containing restricted documents
"""
@register_snippet
@python_2_unicode_compatible  # provide equivalent __unicode__ and __str__ methods on Python 2
class FooSnipet(models.Model):

        rectricted_document_1 = models.ForeignKey(
        'RestrictedDocument',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
    )
    rectricted_document_2 = models.ForeignKey(
        'RestrictedDocument',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
    )
        ....
        and many more
        ....
```

Maybe I am overcomplicating all this and there is another way of doing. Any suggestion will be super welcome! Thank you veeery much :)

Answer (score 2):

The `Document` model doesn't support a `get_upload_to` method like images do. However, as of Django 1.10 it's possible to override the `file` field of `AbstractDocument`:

```
from wagtail.wagtaildocs.models import AbstractDocument

class RestrictedDocument(AbstractDocument):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='restricted', verbose_name=_('file'))
```

I'm not sure that this will help much, though - the views in the Wagtail admin that handle document uploads have no way of knowing that they should save the document through the `RestrictedDocument` model, rather than the default Document class.

Implementing view restrictions on documents within Wagtail is currently a work in progress (https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/3245, https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/1420).

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. You may like to edit it to inherit from `AbstractDocument` instead of `Document`, otherwise django will yell `Local field "file" in class 'RestrictedDocument' clashes with field of the same name from base class 'Document'.` I cannot make it work due to WagtailAdmin issues as you predicted, if I manage to solve it I will post it, otherwhise Wagtail will make the work by their own. Thanks anyway!